# Pyspark command giving error as directory not found error

Tags: java, python, macos, apache-spark, pyspark

I have installed both ApacheSpark and Pyspark on Anaconda (**@ OS Mojave in Macbook and I don't have Hadoop installed!**). But **pyspark** command is not working in terminal and is giving the following error:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pyspark: line 24: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pyspark: line 77: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pyspark: line 77: exec: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/bin/spark-submit: cannot execute: No such file or directory

**These are my environment variables:**

```
export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/spark" #version 1.6
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2]"
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```

**I have python 3.8 and apacheSpark 3.0.0** .
Please help!

Comment: remove everything, then again `pip install pyspark`, and use it straight from python in jupyter, as a classic module.

Answer (score 1):

The hassle-free way to install is by using

```py
findspark
```

download .tgz file from the spark [website](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) which comes with Hadoop binaries

```
pip install findspark
```

In Python:

```py
import findspark

finspark.init('\path\to\extracted\binaries\folder')

import pyspark
```